# One function to detect NaN, NA, Inf, -Inf, etc.?

Tags: r, nan, na, r-faq

Is there a single function in R that determines if a value is `NA`, `NaN`, `Inf`, `-Inf`, or otherwise not a well-formed number?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You want `is.finite`

```
> is.finite(NA)
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(NaN)
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(Inf)
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(1L)
[1] TRUE
> is.finite(1.0)
[1] TRUE
> is.finite("A")
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(pi)
[1] TRUE
> is.finite(1+0i)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Note that `is.finite(TRUE)` also returns `TRUE`.

Comment: @kohske: Good point.  `is.finite(FALSE)` also returns `TRUE`.  This is likely because `TRUE` and `FALSE` are just integers.

Comment: True and false aren't integers - but they will be coerced without error/warning message

Comment: @hadley: I wasn't clear; thanks for clarifying. I was referring to R booleans being 32-bit integers at the C level, not that `is.integer(TRUE)` would return `TRUE`.