# Omit NAs from one vector of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, na

```
BK<- [1  2  3;   
      4  NA 6;   
      7  8  NA;  
      10 11 NA]
```

How to remove rows containing NAs from column 2 without removing rows containing NAs from column 3 in R?

Many thanks!

Comment: tool? I'm using R studio?

Comment: ok, added the R tag, you might get some answers now :)

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773189/remove-na-nan-inf-in-a-matrix?rq=1

Comment: That's not how you construct a matrix in R, but `BK[!is.na(BK[, 2]), ]`

Comment: R-fugee from Matlab no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BK[is.na(BK[,1:2])] <- 0
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    0    8
[3,]    3    6   NA
```

## data

```
    BK <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,8,NA),3,3)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm being slow, but this doesnt answer my question? NAs are still removed from column 3?

Comment: @Brooke Please find the updated soultion

Comment: @Brooke How about the updated code, do you feel it right way to implement