# Error in regression in r

Tags: r

I have two data frames df1 and df2. both of them have 240 obs. of 204 variables. I have checked and there are no missing or NA values in those files. However when I regress by this formula:

```
library(broom)
fit4 <- lapply(names(df1), function(x){
  dd = tidy(lm(df1[[x]] ~ df2[[x]]))
  data.frame(name = x, dd)})
```

It shows the following error messages:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
>   :    NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error itself states, it might be due to NaN values or to infinite values, so you will need to delete those values or assign a zero to them.

To remove NaN from the whole data frame, you will need to create a function (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142117/how-to-replace-nan-value-with-zero-in-a-huge-data-frame)).

```
is.nan.data.frame <- function(x)
do.call(cbind, lapply(x, is.nan))

dd[is.nan(dd)] <- 0
```

For the infinite numbers, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773189/remove-na-nan-inf-in-a-matrix). The two faster methods are to remove all infinite values:

```
dd[!rowSums(!is.finite(dd)),]
```

or to replace them with 0:

```
dd[!is.finite(dd)] <- 0
```