# Remove infinite values from a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix `m` in R , and I would like to remove `-Inf` values , and then calculate the `colMeans` of all columns. How can I do this in R?

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 3, 4, -Inf, 6, 7, 4, -Inf, 6, 0, 1, 3) , nrow = 3)
m
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]     1  -Inf    4    0
[2,]     3   6    -Inf   1
[3,]     4   7      6    3
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518245/one-function-to-detect-nan-na-inf-inf-etc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `is.finite`. I presume this is how you wish to "remove" those `-Inf` values:

```
m[!is.finite(m)] <- NA
colMeans(m, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: We also have `is.infinite` at our disposal. Difference is trivial here - negating `is.finite` will select the same elements unless there are also `NaN` values. (But assigning to the smaller set of elements returned by `is.infinite` might be more efficient on huge matrices.)