# how to deal with NaN, Na and Inf to calculate mean in R? + after measuring community detection metrics

Tags: r, nan, mean, na

my question is that , what is the best way or the right way to deal with `NaN` and `NA` and `Inf` to calculate `mean` in R:

- change Inf to NA also and as `is.Na(NaN)` is `TRUE` also, simply use the `na.rm= TRUE`in `mean` Function or
- change all to zero  and then calculate the `mean` function.

values that I want to calculate mean for are the values comes from measuring `conductance` and `expansion` for community detection algorithm as defined [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1772690.1772755)

Thanks

Comment: Well changing them to zero gives you a different result. `mean(c(1,NA,8,9,NA), na.rm=TRUE) # [1] 6; mean(c(1,0,8,9,0)) # [1] 3.6` so I'd probably use `na.rm`

Comment: thanks for your comment @RichardScriven yes,my question is that which one is better and why? ... why would you use na.rm ?

Comment: Because `NA` means "Not Available". That does not mean that value is zero. We don't know what it is. It means that element should be excluded from calculations.  We cannot assume that it is zero. It's like someone leaving out an answer on a survey.  Would you fill in that answer for them if they choose to omit it?

Comment: @RichardScriven, consider that after some calculation you get Na , NaN and Inf in your values , to me is that you are omitting that value and not considering it at all but comsidering your point as well I don't know what is the best way ?!

Comment: @RichardScriven what about `inf` and `NaN` ?

Comment: `NaN` means "Not A Number" and infinity is a mathematical value.  You'll have to make some decisions.  The question is a bit broad and is also likely to attract differing opinions.

Comment: @RichardScriven well thanks, i will edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: The answer to this depends on what you're trying to do, and it's not really a programming question.

Comment: Here you go, this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518245/one-function-to-detect-nan-na-inf-inf-etc?rq=1

Comment: thanks @RichardScriven, I do see that link but my question is more of a conceptual question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would distinguish between the cases of NA/NaN/Infinity and the rest. I would certainly not convert them to zero as this would distort the result significantly while at the same time, not having any real mathematical sense.

If a value is NA, then it is not, as the name suggests, available
If it is NaN, then it is not a number
And Inf... well, it's infinity.

In all these cases you cannot get an average. Exclude them, and perhaps try to see why they appear (if you can, have to, need to, etc).