# How to get consistent output when checking for infinite values

Tags: r

```
# works fine
check = c(1,2,3,4, Inf)
out   = check[-which(check == Inf)]
print(out)
# [1] 1 2 3 4

# does not work fine 
check = c(1,2,3,4)
out   = check[-which(check == Inf)]
print(out)
# numeric(0)
```

The first example creates an `out`variable with the correct values 1,2,3,4. The second variable creates an empty variable `out` as the which function returns integer(0) and apparently remove integer(0) from the check vector gives 0 elements.

I know how to write this in several lines but is there a one-liner for this?

Comment: Try `check[ !is.na(check) ]` ? After edit: `check[ is.finite() ]` ?

Comment: I changed the question to Inf. But this is working fine for Inf as well, thanks. Why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: you can also just drop the `which` and write `check[check != Inf]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, `is.finite()`:

```
# example 1
check <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, Inf)
out <- check[ is.finite(check) ]
out
# [1] 1 2 3 4

# example 2
check <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
out <- check[ is.finite(check) ]
out
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Related post about: [is.finite()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518245).

Answer (score 1):

```
check = c(1,2,3,4)
out   = check[!is.infinite(check)]
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is technically a oneliner...

```
out   = if (any(is.na(check))) {check[-which(is.na(check))]} else {check}
```

Comment: It is, but the other solution is cleaner ;)